How to use AWS Secret Manger in JavaScript file hosted on ECS container
I have a GitHub project which contains a react-server and node-server. Currently I have it setup so that my Dockerfile takes both of these services and uses supervisord.conf / nginx.conf files to start both services simultaneously on different ports.
It currently runs and the react app is accessible at http://jermasearch.com/ , while the backend node-server is accessible at http://jermasearch.com/internal-api/dbTest
I want to edit my server.js node-server file so that when the user requests the route /secretTest it gets my secret I have stored inside AWS Secret Manager:

As you can see on US-west-2, I have a secret stored with the name algoliaDbIndex_Secret_Name, this is the secret I am trying to retrieve inside server.js, but I've been unable to do so.
My ecs container uses this IAM group which includes the secret read write permission

And as you can see my container task definition uses this IAM group:

I tried to follow this guide on how to use the AWS Javascript v3 SDK to get a secret:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_secrets-manager_code_examples.html
And I tried to replicate the code sample they give from GitHub with more context:
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/secrets-manager/actions/get-secret-value.js
const algoliasearch = require("algoliasearch");
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = 3030;

// Enable CORS for all routes
app.use(cors());

// Fetch data from Algolia database
async function fetchDataFromAlgolia() {
  return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
    try {
      resolve("wip");
      /*
      // Setup DB connection creds
      const client = algoliasearch('', '');
      const index = client.initIndex('');

      // Perform the search
      index.search('super mario', {
        hitsPerPage: 1000,
      }).then(({ hits }) => {
        console.log(`Found ${hits.length} hits.`);
        resolve({ "search": "completed" });
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Error making query: ", error);
        resolve({ "error": error });
      });
      */
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("fetchDataFromAlgolia() Error: ", error);
      resolve({ "error": error });
    }
  });
}

app.get('/fetchSubtitles', async (req, res) => {
  let queryResults = await fetchDataFromAlgolia();
  res.send(queryResults);
});

app.get('/dbtest', async (req, res) => {
  res.send('dbTest route working');
});

// Retrieve secrets from AWS
async function retrieveSecretsFromAWS() {
  return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
    let secretVal = "default";
    try {
        const {GetSecretValueCommand, SecretsManagerClient,} = require("@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager");
        const client = new SecretsManagerClient();
        const response = await client.send(
          new GetSecretValueCommand({
            SecretId: "algoliaDbIndex_Secret_Name",
          }),
        );
        secretVal = response;
    
    } catch (error) {
      secretVal = `Error getting aws secret: ${error}`
    }
    resolve(secretVal); 
  })
}

app.get('/secretTest', async (req, res) => {
  let awsSecret = await retrieveSecretsFromAWS()
  res.send({ 'awsSecret': awsSecret });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
  // Debugging environment variables
  console.log('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:', process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID);
  console.log('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:', process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
  console.log('AWS_REGION:', process.env.AWS_REGION);
});


But my code fails with an error:
{
    "awsSecret": "Error getting aws secret: CredentialsProviderError: Could not load credentials from any providers"
}

When I push my server.js code below to my production aws instance and visit the url: http://www.jermasearch.com/internal-api/secretTest
What am I doing wrong?

It does not look like you are setting your AWS credentials anywhere. There are multiple ways you can define your AWS credentials. You can use environment variables, credentials or config file, etc. Here is one document explaining the order of operations AWS uses in where it will look for credentials: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/v1/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html

I see, my code gets hosted in an ec2 container so i need to find out how to sign in / authenticate in javascript from inside my container

I've added an S3 read only ami role to my container service, but am still getting the same error.

You need a role that can read from Secrets Manager, not S3

I checked and added the SecretReadWrite permission to my IAM role, but am still getting the error Error getting aws secret: CredentialsProviderError: Could not load credentials from any providers I updated my question with images for all the aws groups / proof

Did your debug logs of the env vars show that they were populated?
